# How do I export a HTML canvas to an image that can be downloaded?

Tags: javascript, html, download, html5-canvas, export

I currently have an HTML canvas that interpolates data points and I would like to take the displayed canvas below and allow the user to press a button and download it to their computer.[image]

I have very basic experience with the HTMl canvas in general, but how would I do that? I assume that I have to write the and associate it with a button either on the canvas or on the webpage. Which one would be easier?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function downloadCanvasContentFn(canvasId = "", fileName = "") {
    let id = "canvasDownloadLinkId";
    //get the link if already exisit in page
    let link = document.getElementById(id);

    //if not create one
    if (link == null) {
        //Create a link
        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.id = id;
    }

    //set file name
    link.download = fileName + '.png';
    //get canvas as data URL
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL()
    //click -- this will download
    link.click();
}
```

The above mentioned function can be a reusable function to help download the canvas as a file. Now just pass the canvasid and the file name for the image. :)

Comment: Would i create a button to call this function?

Comment: You can either create a button or call this on user-behavior.

Comment: I have my button coded like this... `<button onclick="downloadCanvasContentFn()">Download image of conditions</button>`. When the page is loading, i can download a blank image, but when I wait for the canvas to load, I cannot download any image.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured the problem. Thank you so much for your help